# computing the percentage change with negative numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a columns with the following V:

```
Voltage
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-46.1
-45.6
```

i wrote the following function to do that:

```
def Percentage_change( data):

    list2=data

    list1=[]

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i==0:
            list1.append(0)
        else:
            try:
                list1.append((float(list2[i])-float(list2[i-1]))/float(list2[i-1]))
            except ZeroDivisionError: list1.append(0)
                #print(" your are trying to divide something par zero",float(list2[i-1]))

    return list1
```

Now i want to check if the % change is greater than a percentage. I have the following check:

```
per_change = Percentage_change(v) #v is the voltage values

for i in range(len(per_change)):
    if (per_change[i]<=-0.2 or per_change[i]>=0.2):
        print("too much percentage change")
```

The problem is that, for the last value (-45.6) execute as true while in reality, its percentage change is -0.01.  What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your program doesn't print anything [on my machine](http://ideone.com/GZRp4k). Are you sure the code you have here is exactly identical to the code you're running?

Comment: I don't think this is related to the issue you're having, but a general suggestion: Rather than iterating on `range(len(some_sequence))` and then indexing the sequence with the value, I suggest iterating directly on the sequence items with `for item in sequence`. In your first function, since you want adjacent values, I'd use `for prev, curr in zip(list2, list2[1:])` and compute `(float(curr) - float(prev)) / float(prev)`. In the second function I'd use `for change in per_change` and compute `abs(change) > 0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make an approximate calculation (with only absolute numbers):

`((float(list2[i])-float(list2[i-1]))` is at the last value pair `0.5`

`float(list2[i-1])` is at the last value pair approx. `50`

Thus, the devision is approx. `0.5 / 50`. Thus `v` is approx. `0.01` (approx. one per cent of the total voltage).

But, your limit is `0.2` (which corresponds to twenty percent)

I conclude: the limit of `0.2` is not hurt. The print will not come.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Percentage_change(data):
    abs_change = [(data[i] - data[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(data))]
    percent_change = []
    for i in range(len(abs_change)):
        if abs_change[i] is 0.0:
            percent_change.append(0.0)
        elif abs_change[i] is not 0.0:
            percent_change.append(100.0*abs_change[i]/abs(float(data[i])))
#Depending on what you want you can add the following line 
    percent_change.insert(0, 0.0)
    return percent_change

V = [-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-46.1,-45.6]
per_change = Percentage_change(V)

for value in per_change:
    if abs(value)> 20.0:
        print 'too much percentage change'
```

Output:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0845986984815619]

Note: This code works good as long as the list 'data' does not contain 0.